# Is there a way to get next day price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am new to Pine Script. I need to draw support and resistance line. The rules for resistance is as follow :

```
If today's closing price is greater than Previous (Day-1) closing price  AND
   today's closing price is greater than Next (Day+1) closing price AND
   today's closing price is greater than Next (Day+2) closing price AND
   today's closing price is greater than Next (Day+3) closing price   then
   Resistance is today's closing price
else
   Resistance is previous (Day-1) closing price
```

I don't know how to get Day+1, Day+2, Day+3 Price in pine script.

Answer (score 0):

You can not forward reference in pine so you have to refactor the logical operation from the perspective of close(day + 3) being the current close.

```
resistance = close[3] > close and close[3] > close[1] and close[3] > close[2] and close[3] > close[4] ? close[3] : close[4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. First, i need to revise that resistance line is based on high (not close). Then i modify your formula to be : resistance = high[3] > high and high[3] > high[1] and high[3] > high[2] and high[3] > high[4] ? high[3] : high[4]

But the result is not correct as i expect that resistance line should be shifted to 4 previous candle.  Let's use this example : 
Here is highest price for 5 candle bar :   ...,1000, 1020, 1010, 1000, 1010.  Then the resistance for each candle is : 1000 (suppose this is previous resistance), 1020, 1020, 1020, 1020

Comment: You can use the `offset` parameter for `plot()` to shift the line, however, remember that we can not reference data in the future, so the value can not be determined until the script has reached day+3, which means a delay for the resistance value to be determined. Even when the script is executing on historical bars, it can not reference data ahead of the bar it is currently up to.

Comment: i use offset -3, it seems work.  But i lost resistance indicator of 3 last candle becase of shifting. Is there any trick to handle this case?